# filtering pymongo list_collection_names throws type error

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Why should the following code throw `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`?

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('x.x.x.x', username='xxxxxx', 
            password='yyyyyyy', authSource='zzzz', authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256')
mydb = myclient["db"]    
filter = {"name": {"$regex": r"^(?!system\.)"}}
collection = mydb.list_collection_names(filter=filter)
collection.sort()
filtered_names = list(filter(lambda x: "test" in x, collection ))
```

It is pymongo 4.4.1

Comment: Off topic, but does anything apart from `$regex` works in `filter`? It's not stated in the documentation, but when I try to use an `$ne` or `$nin` I get an error like this every time: `can't get regex from filter doc not a regex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('x.x.x.x', username='xxxxxx', 
            password='yyyyyyy', authSource='zzzz', authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256')
mydb = myclient["db"]    
my_filter = {"name": {"$regex": r"^(?!system\.)"}}
collection = mydb.list_collection_names(filter=my_filter )
collection.sort()
filtered_names = list(filter(lambda x: "test" in x, collection ))
```

Avoiding using built-ins (such as `filter`) as variable names is good practice and will prevent this kind of slip-up.